# How can I convert a camera view to a top view cartesian plane in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video stream coming from a camera from an angle, I want to have a top view of the frame but only for a moving point. The image doesn't necessarily be wrapped or stretched. 
All I want is mapping the range of pointer from the original image to cartesian plane (top view)
Refer to the images below.

code so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
ix = 0
iy = 0


def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global ix, iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        ix = x
        iy = y


img = cv2.imread("./maxresdefault.jpg")
h, w, c = img.shape
ones = np.zeros((h, w))
left, top = 50, 50
right, bottom = w - 50, h - 50
cv2.namedWindow('main_image')
while True:
    ones_copy = ones.copy()
    cv2.setMouseCallback('main_image', draw_circle)
    cv2.rectangle(ones, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.circle(ones_copy, (ix, iy), 2, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("main_image", img)
    cv2.imshow("ones", ones_copy)
    cv2.waitKey(32)
# coords = [[54, 199], [520, 336], [542, 177], [233, 121]]
# coords = [[233, 121]]
# y = ((x / 99.0) * 2) - 1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? Do you want to make the selected area square? Because that will involve warping/stretching. Or do you only want to rotate the region of interest? What do you mean with 'moving point'? It really helps if you can create a desired result (using for example paint).

Comment: I mentioned, "The image doesn't necessarily be wrapped or stretched." I want 4 coordinates of the original image mapped with 4 coordinates of the white rectangle of the black image. Means, if I move my cursor (121,233) of the original image the white pointer in black image should be at the top left of the white rectangle

Comment: Thanks, that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the image does not need to be transformed, but the underlying pixelspace does. I'm not an expert, but AFAIK the math is quite complex. So if you only care about the result I suggest taking the easy approach:

Create a black image with the size of the input frame
Draw a white dot at cursor position
Transform the black image to a rectangle (described [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#perspective-transformation))

Note that the dot will also be streched. If you want the cartesian x,y position, you can look for the first white pixel in the image array or you can calculate the average position. Or for example use [findcontours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html) and then [findEnclosingCircle](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#minimum-enclosing-circle) to get the center x,y.

For reference I added an example, but since this is just the process linked to above, (with some mouse interface mixed in), I won't explain it in detail. Note that the order in which the corner points are clicked is relevant, must be clockwise.

Result (cursor was on plate):
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_ori = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
img = img_ori.copy()
base = np.zeros((img_ori.shape[:2]))

l = []
setup = True
m = 0

def getTransform(points):
    # from documentation linked above
    pts1 = np.float32(points)
    pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[300,300],[0,300]])

    return cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

def processMouse(event,x,y,flags,params):
    global l,setup,m
    if setup:
        # create ROI + getTransform when 4 corners are clicked
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            l.append([x,y])
            cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 5,(255,0,0),3)
            cv2.imshow('IMG',img)
            if(len(l)) == 4:
                m = getTransform(l)
                setup = False
    else:
        # draw mouse position

        # with image
        img2 = img_ori.copy()
        cv2.circle(img2, (x,y), 5,(0,0,255),-1)
        dst =   cv2.warpPerspective(np.float32(img2), m, (300,300))
        dst = np.array(dst, dtype='uint8')
        cv2.imshow('IMG2',dst)

        # black 
        img3 = base.copy()
        cv2.circle(img3, (x,y), 5,(255),-1)
        dst =   cv2.warpPerspective(np.float32(img3), m, (300,300))
        dst = np.array(dst, dtype='uint8')
        cv2.imshow('IMG3',dst)


cv2.namedWindow('IMG')
cv2.setMouseCallback("IMG",processMouse)
cv2.imshow('IMG',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```